# Same function on two separate elements with the same class

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
    var togView = document.querySelector('.toggle-view');
    var list = document.querySelector('.pt-list');

    togView.onclick = function() {
        const isAdded = togView.classList.toggle('list');
        list.classList.toggle('list', isAdded);
    };
```

Which I'm using to toggle a class called `.list` on and off on this little element called `toggle-view` and on a sibling element called `pt-list`

```
<div class="toggle-view">
   <span class="thumb-view">Thumbnail View</span> | <span class="list-view">List View</span>
</div>

<div class="pt-list"></div>
```

This worked fine until I added another `<div class="toggle-view">` element. Now only the first iteration of the `toggle-view` element works.

How could I get this function to work on both `<div class="toggle-view">` elements independently without having to assign them an ID and duplicate the function?

I found a similar question on here from a few years ago and from what I understand, I need to use `this`?, but I can't figure out how to apply that to what's happening in my function.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: The docs for [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) say that only the first match is returned. Use querySelectorAll for multiple selections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does querySelector only select the first element and how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012836/why-does-queryselector-only-select-the-first-element-and-how-can-i-fix-this)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-view')"` and querySelectorAll will return a list of html elements with class name of `".toggle-view"`. Then use foreach loop through this list and add click listener to trigger click event independently.

See the snippet below, the result might be vary, but logic is there:

```js
var togView = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-view');
    var list = document.querySelector('.pt-list');

togView.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const isAdded = button.classList.toggle('list');
    list.classList.toggle('list', isAdded);
    //Test for showing the className onto html element, independently
    button.innerHTML  = button.classList.value
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="toggle-view">
   <span class="thumb-view">Thumbnail View</span> | <span class="list-view">List View</span>
</div>

<div class="toggle-view">
   <span class="thumb-view">Thumbnail View</span> | <span class="list-view">List View</span>
</div>



<div class="pt-list"></div>
```